# How to modify a prefix of a Kotlin sequence but retain the tail?

Tags: iterator, sequence, kotlin, tail

Kotlin provides `take` and `takeWhile` methods which let one to take first `n` items of a `Sequence<T>` and process them separately as another sequence, for example, `drop` some of them, `map` to other values etc.

But when I use `take` and `takeWhile`, the tail of the sequence is dropped.

Now, given a *once-constrained*  sequence, how do I transform its arbitrary prefix to another sequence retaining the tail if it remains?

Example:

```
val seq = (1..10).asSequence().constrainOnce() 
// emits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

val modified = seq.changePrefix { take(5).map { -1 * it } }
// emits -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

How do I do the same for more than one prefix?

Example:

```
val seq = (1..10).asSequence().constrainOnce()

val modified = seq.changePrefixes(
        { take(3).map { it * -1 } },
        { drop(1).take(3).map { it * 100 } },
        { map { 0 } }
)

//emits -1, -2, -3, 500, 600, 700, 0, 0, 0
```

*Note: the question is intentionally asked and [answered by the author](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `Sequence<T>` is once-constrained, it means that it is not allowed to create more than one `Iterator` from it. Therefore the solution is to create one iterator and produce both the changed prefix and the remaining tail from it.

The `Iterator<T>`'s [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/kotlin.-iterator/as-sequence.html) method proves to be useful here as it creates a sequence backed by the iterator. What remains is just to concatenate the sequences.

Here's how you do it for one change:

```
val seq = (1..10).asSequence().constrainOnce()
val modified = seq.iterator().let { iter -> 
    iter.asSequence().take(5).map { it * -1 } + iter.asSequence()
}
```

Note that two sequences are created from the same iterator, but it's OK because

- `Sequence`s are evaluated lazily
- The two sequences are used together and do not leak out
- Evaluation of the second sequence in concatenation will start after the first one finishes

And here's how to generalize it to arbitrary number of sequence operators:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.changePrefixes(vararg operators: Sequence<T>.() -> Sequence<T>)
: Sequence<T> {
    val i = iterator()
    return operators.fold(emptySequence<T>()) { acc, it -> acc + i.asSequence().it() } + 
            i.asSequence()
}
```

This `fold` produces a chain of concatenated sequences provided by `operators` from the sequences backed by the iterator `i`, and then appends the unmodified tail to the `fold` result.

The limitation of this implementation is that when an operator includes `takeWhille`, the rejected item will be dropped and won't be emitted into the next sequence.