# How to make to separate isolated traversals of a Sequence<> that is subject to constrainOnce()?

Tags: kotlin, iterator, sequence

I know constrainOnce() constrains a Kotlin Sequence to only be constrained once, but it seems
very restrictive. I want to do something for the first 3 (eg) elements and then do something else
to the elements after that:

```
class TestClassGeneric {
    @Test
    fun t1() {
        val seq1 = sequenceOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).constrainOnce()
        seq1.take(3).forEach() { println(it) }
        seq1.drop(3).forEach() { println(it) }

    }
}
```

The code fails at the line with the drop() in it, because a second traversal of the Sequence is attmpted. Why is this ? I haven't iterated *beyond* the first 3 items yet !

I would expect it to fail if I used `drop(2)` or `drop(1)` but failing at `drop(3)` seems very restrictive.

Is it really supposed to just discard the rest of the Sequence ? How does one do something to the first few elements, passing its tail as a subsequence to somewhere else.

There is a answered-by-author question [How to modify a prefix of a Kotlin sequence but retain the tail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35114716/19247829) but I can't understand how the answer he gives works. It involves using just a single `Iterator` and `asSequence()` on that Iterator. However, I can't make out whether the Iterator is supposed to advance between successive usages of it. Also, is there any significance to doing all this inside a scoping function, `.let{}` ?

I generate Sequences and need to do something based on what it starts with. I created a wrapper class for this `HybridSequence(ps:Sequence): Sequence`, wherein the `init{}` performed a `take(1)` on the wrapped Sequence wrote it into a `List`, and set a readable property based on that first element,

It provides an iterator which would yield that first element from the list, and then the tail of what was passed (using drop(2) on the input). Obviously this loses lazy evaluation for the first element, but this is OK for me.

Anyway, it fails as the underlying Sequence appears to get disposed of when I try to use the drop(2). My code is a bit cumbersome, so I created the above minimal version.

I don't actually /need/ my `Sequence`s to be `constrainOnce()` but I would like to make it robust enough to support such.

(Edit - a day later, after realising the single-iterator condition)

```
open class HeaderedSequence<T>(val headerSize: Int, sequence: Sequence<T>): Sequence<T> { 
      private val wrappedIterator: Iterator<T>
    private val header = ArrayList<T>()
    private val newSequence: Sequence<T>

    val headerCount: Int

    init {
        wrappedIterator = sequence.iterator()
        var loops = 0
        while(wrappedIterator.hasNext() && loops<headerSize) {
            header.add(wrappedIterator.next())
            ++loops
        }
        headerCount = header.count()
        newSequence = header.asSequence() + wrappedIterator.asSequence()
    }

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<T> {
        return newSequence.iterator()
    }

    fun getHeaderItemOrNull(index: Int): T? {
        require(index in 0 until headerSize)
        return if (index < headerCount) header[index] else null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to not think about this in the terms that we create a "smart" sequence which observes what operations we run on it and it tries to intelligently re-use the data. That would be very hard to do and we would probably fail anyway, because the sequence can't know what is our use case exactly, so it can't optimize itself.

Instead, if you often have a need to split a sequence into a head of some size and a tail, then we can implement this specific case very easily:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val seq1 = sequenceOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).constrainOnce()
    val (head, tail) = seq1.headTail(3)
    tail.forEach { println(it) } // 4, 5, 6, 7
    head.forEach { println(it) } // 1, 2, 3
}

fun <T> Sequence<T>.headTail(headSize: Int): Pair<Sequence<T>, Sequence<T>> {
    val iter = iterator()
    return List(headSize) { iter.next() }.asSequence() to iter.asSequence()
}
```

It is simple: at the time we run `headTail()` it reads the head and stores it in a list, then it wraps the remaining iterator over the tail into another sequence.

Of course, in this solution the head is read eagerly, only the tail is lazy. That makes sense if the head is often small. Depending on our needs, we could implement a solution where the whole head is read only after we access the first item (a little more complicated) or even that it reads item by item (even more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@broot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77854259/6395627). However, as I understand [your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77853122/how-to-make-to-separate-isolated-traversals-of-a-sequence-that-is-subject-to-c/77854416#comment137250672_77853216), you need the "tail" sequence to still include the header elements for the API that consumes it. And ideally, only the header elements should be eagerly evaluated. That only requires a small modification to broot's code:

```kotlin
fun <T> Sequence<T>.fetchPrefix(size: Int): Pair<List<T>, Sequence<T>> {
    val iter = iterator()
    val prefix = List(size) { iter.next() }
    val sequence = prefix.asSequence() + iter.asSequence()
    return prefix to sequence
}
```

The above can be used like so:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val (prefix, sequence) = createSequence().fetchPrefix(3)
    println("Pefix = $prefix")

    val result = sequence.toList()
    println("Result = $result")
}

fun createSequence() = (1..7).asSequence()
        .constrainOnce()
        .onEach { println("Prociessing $it") }
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Processing 1
Processing 2
Processing 3
Pefix = [1, 2, 3]
Processing 4
Processing 5
Processing 6
Processing 7
Result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

As you can see, the first three elements are eagerly evaluated and put into a list. It's not until the returned sequence is consumed that the rest of the elements are evaluated, yet the end result still contains the first three elements.

---

If you don't want to deal with the `Pair` in the caller code then you can add this function:

```kotlin
fun <T, C : MutableCollection<in T>> Sequence<T>.fetchPrefixTo(
        size: Int,
        collection: C
): Sequence<T> {
    return fetchPrefix(size).also { collection.addAll(it.first) }.second
}
```

Though it will require you to pre-allocate the prefix collection.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the 'header' elements are still iterated out in order, just as with the original sequence. This is because some of the consuming code is not header-aware. Yes, only the header should be evaluated.eagerly. However, for reasons of compat with existing code, I need this.headet to be available /before/ either part is iterated.

Comment: "_I need this.headet to be available /before/ either part is iterated._" -- I'm not sure I understand that requirement. How do you expect to get `n` "header" elements out of the sequence without iterating `n` elements? Note the code in my answer gives you the `n` header elements (the "prefix"), available to you immediately, _and_ a sequence containing _all_ the elements (including the header) in the original order. That sequence can be consumed at any arbitrary point in the future, or never. All elements after the header are _lazy_. This is shown by the output of the example.

Comment: I mean I want the first few elements to be read eagerly and kept inside the object. Obviously, they do actually have to be 'read' from the underlying sequence, but I need to make a wrapper sequence which, when iterated, will present to the caller those same few header elements /again/. The solution that I used is now edited into the original question, but I haven't completed unit tests on it yet.

Comment: From a cursory glance at your solution I only see two differences from mine: (1) You allow the source sequence to have _less_ than the requested number of prefix elements, which my solution can easily be modified to do the same, and (2) you are wrapping everything in a class that implements `Sequence`, which I don't really see the benefit of, but perhaps that makes sense for your real code. Note I'm not demanding you accept my solution or anything, I'd just like to understand which of your requirements my solution doesn't meet.

Answer (score 0):

Your woes stem from what happens when you call `drop`, which basically creates a new iterator which breaks the `constrainOnce` (since you can only make an iterator over it once)

`.mapIndexed` is what you want if I understand your requirements correctly

```
fun t1() {
    val seq1 = sequenceOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).constrainOnce()

    var trigger = false;

    val newSeq = seq1
        .mapIndexed { index, value ->
            // Add in some extra state
            if(index > 3) {
                trigger = true
            }

            when {
                index in 0..2 -> {
                    value
                }
                index in 3..5 && trigger -> {
                    -1 * value
                }
                else -> {
                    value * value
                }
            }
        }

    newSeq.iterator().forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

You can key off the index or external state to do whatever you want to an arbitrary sequence this retains the lazy behavior.  That predicate just evaluates once each time and the state can be changed in between iterations.

Comment: I'll add if you pass the original sequence into a function and have that state (like `trigger`) as a local variable to the function, that state will have an independent memory, so you can create independent versions of the sequence.  I suspect that's what your `HybridSequence` is doing

Comment: I have misexplained what I am trying to do, I am trying to implement a 'look ahead': as soon as the wrapping happens, the first n items are read into an internal list, a  'header' to be available before any elements are traversed (obviously they will be read internally.) I want this 'header' to be available 'before' an external agent starts to read the sequence. When it does start to read it will transparently read the first N items from the internal list, and the rest from the tail of the original sequence. It needs to do this in the context of a single iterator. I will update the q later

Comment: @fiatCurrency You provided a very detailed description of one potential way to solve this. Did you try to implement this idea? What problem did you face when you tried?

Comment: I now have a solution and many people have given good ideas. My main sticking point, however, was that I didn't understand that you couldn't have multiple iterators: I just assumed you could have as many as you liked, so long as they didn't overlap. This is not the case. So it appears that the first answer to this question is the one which resolved my sticking point. I don't know if I can accept multiple answers as the correct one.